# Where does default external libraries in an Android project comes from?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

If I create a new Android project using Android Studio and remove all dependencies by default like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dependencies"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" }
}
// I remove all dependencies
dependencies {
}
```

If I check the external libraries in `Project -> External libraries` this is the result.
[image]

## Question

I'm reading gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) and this case is confusing. Where does the external libraries of the picture above comes from?

Comment: Did you sync your project with the Gradle files? I just tried reproducing your scenario, and once I did the sync, the only dependencies that I see are for Kotlin.

Comment: You are right. I had to create a different project to replicate it. I'm going to update the question and the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does the external libraries of the picture above comes from?

They are coming from your plugins, specifically these two:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

If you comment those out, you should have no dependencies other than the Android platform JAR.

Comment: Hello sir, can you please help me in this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61708063/6891563